# pop-up a list of enabled minor modes in a readable format?

Tags: minor-mode

I like to keep my modeline pretty minimal, so I'm hiding most minor-mode lighters. Occasionally I want to check which minor-modes are enabled, and it would be nice if I could trigger a pop-up that listed them and that I could easily dismiss with `q` or `ESC`. I'm imagining an interface like [which-key](https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key) uses.

I know about `C-h m`, but I'm looking for a solution that looks less like,

```
Enabled minor modes: Async-Bytecomp-Package Auto-Composition
Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption Auto-Revert Buffer-Face Column-Number
Delete-Selection Diff-Auto-Refine Drag-Stuff-Global Electric-Indent
Electric-Pair Evil Evil-Commentary Evil-Local File-Name-Shadow
Font-Lock Global-Eldoc Global-Font-Lock Global-Git-Commit
```

and more like

```
Async-Bytecomp-Package    Delete-Selection     Evil-Local
Auto-Composition          Diff-Auto-Refine     File-Name-Shadow
Auto-Compression          Drag-Stuff-Global    Font-Lock
Auto-Encryption           Electric-Indent      Global-Eldoc
Auto-Revert               Electric-Pair        Global-Font-Lock
Buffer-Face               Evil                 Global-Git-Commit
Column-Number             Evil-Commentary
```

I also don't need all the extra info that `C-h m` presents (keybindings, descriptions, etc.). Plus `C-h m` forces me to switch to it's newly opened window before I can kill it.

Does anyone know of a package that does something like this?

Comment: check out [`manage-minor-mode`](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/manage-minor-mode)

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan Perfect, thanks!

Comment: Posted my comment as an answer so that it's visible to more people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`helm-describe-modes`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm-describe-modes) uses Helm completion, so you can easily search for and act on modes.

Answer (score 4):

[`manage-minor-mode`](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/manage-minor-mode)  will open a new window which shows two columns of all the *active* minor modes and *inactive* minor modes for the current buffer. You can selectively enable/disable minor modes by pressing <kbd>RET</kbd> or you can also select minor modes to be enabled/disabled for the whole session.

It looks like so :- 
[image]

Comment: Please elaborate a bit. This is essentially a link-only answer, which means it risks being deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to see a list of (at least some of) the minor modes - those that choose to let you access them this way.

Right-click the mode indicator in the mode line (any part of it: major-mode indicator or any minor-mode indicator). This is the part in parentheses.

This pops up a menu (list) of many of the minor modes currently enabled (those that bother to provide mode-line lighters).

You can also use this menu to toggle any of these minor modes on/off.

See the Emacs manual, node [Mode Line](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mode-Line.html) for more information.